# Zod env validation not working with "use client" in Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js13, zod

I am new to **typescript** and **nextjs13** so dont know much about it but the issue I am facing is something related to **client side render** coz as soon as I remove **"use client"** from component it works also I am using Zod to validate env variables.

`src/utils/env.ts (zod validation file)`

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

const envSchema = z.object({
    NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH: z.string().nonempty(),
    JWT_SECRET: z.string().nonempty(),
});

export const env = envSchema.parse(process.env);
```

`.env.local (env var file)`

```js
NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH=someRandomApiKey
JWT_SECRET=someRandomSecret
```

`src/app/signup/page.tsx (component)`

```js
'use client';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { env } from '@/utils/env';

interface pageProps {}

const Signup: FC<pageProps> = ({}) => {
    console.log(env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH);
    return <></>;
};

export default Signup;
```

`Error`

[image]

Thank you

`I tried removing "use client" and it worked but the problem is I want to use the env var on client side so I cant remove use client. Also I am using same env var on server side as well its working fine there in app/api`

Comment: I am having the same issue. The problem occurs only when using the variable in client side. I guess we can use different variables for env starting with _NEXT_PUBLIC__, (which is accessible to both client-side and server-side), and others (which is only available in server-side)

Comment: Same issue for me, I tried creating 2 schemas, one for client and one for server (which extends client) but process.env seems to be an empty object in the env.ts file

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the environment in which server code runs is separated from the client side. Normally you can't access the `process.env` object in the browser. Next js substitutes all `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YOUR_VARIABLE` occurrences with an actual value.

When you import your `env.ts` from the browser the line

```
envSchema.parse(process.env)
```

doesn't work cuz there is no `process.env` in the browser environment.

The only time you need to validate env variables is when the server starts. You don't need to check it with every request from the client side. Once you imported your `env` object from `env.ts` somewhere in the server code you should be fine with validating stuff.

So instead of using `env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH` in your client code, you can use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH` directly. This won't give you any types though.

If you want to have typed `env` object just create a separate `clientEnv.ts` file with explicit references to your client-side variables:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const clientEnvSchema = z.object({
    NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH: z.string().nonempty(),
});

export const clientEnv = clientEnvSchema.parse({
    NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APIAUTH,
}
```

Check the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser